# Error when using SparkR insertInto via databricks

Tags: r, databricks, impala, sparkr

I am trying to insert values from a dataframe into a database table (impala) using SparkR in a databricks notebook:

```
require(SparkR)
test_df <- data.frame(row_no = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
                    ,row_dat = c('dat_2','dat_3','dat_4','dat_5','dat_6','dat_7','dat_8')
                    )
test_df <- as.data.frame(test_df)

sparkR.session()
insertInto(test_df,"db_name.table_name",overwrite = false)
```

I get the error: "*unable to find an inherited method for function ‘insertInto’ for signature ‘"data.frame", "character"’*"

I have checked the connection to this table and using SparkR::collect I can return the data from it no problem. So why isn't the insert working?

Comment: Note line 5 was added just to ensure test_df is a dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `as.data.frame` that returns R dataframe you need to use `as.DataFrame` that returns Spark dataframe that could be used with `insertInto` (see [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html#from-local-data-frames)). Change code to:

```r
require(SparkR)
test_df <- data.frame(row_no = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
                    ,row_dat = c('dat_2','dat_3','dat_4','dat_5','dat_6','dat_7','dat_8')
                    )
test_df <- as.DataFrame(test_df)

sparkR.session()
insertInto(test_df,"db_name.table_name",overwrite = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am now getting the error "error in evaluating the argument 'test' in selecting a method for function 'ifelse': object 'false' not found" - any ideas?

Comment: it should be `FALSE`, not `false` - fixed an example

Comment: You're amazing! Marked as answered - thanks again!